# Datatable: Select values based on datetime

Tags: c#, select, datatable

Having a DataTable with these values (for example):

```
 Quantity       ReferenceDate
87.000000   2011-11-24 15:12:26.990
58.000000   2011-11-24 15:12:26.030
87.000000   2011-11-24 12:18:27.180
58.000000   2011-11-24 13:12:27.027
87.000000   2011-11-24 19:22:27.563
13.000000   2011-11-24 19:40:27.123
```

having a `DateTime` variable that has only the hour, for example

```
DateTime mySelectDate = new DateTime (2011,12,15,19,00,00)
```

how can I obtain the `sum(Quantity)` for the values that "fall" in that hour?

In my example I should get `Sum(Quantity) = 100 (87 + 13)`

Luigi

Answer (score 3):

Using [Linq to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx):

```
DateTime mySelectDate = new DateTime (2011,12,15,19,00,00);
DateTime endDate = mySelectDate.AddHours(1);

var sum = table.Rows.AsEnumerable().
               .Where(row =>       
               {
                 var referenceDate = row.Field<DateTime>("ReferenceDate");
                 return ((referenceDate >= mySelectDate ) && (referenceDate < endDate));
               })
               .Sum(row => row.Field<double>("Quantity"));
```

Comment: Another little variation.

Having this values in my DataTable: 


ReferenceDate   Quantity 
2011-10-02 23:00:00.000 87.000000
2011-10-02 23:00:00.000 58.000000
2011-10-03 00:00:00.000 3.000000
2011-10-03 01:00:00.000 1.000000
2011-10-03 02:00:00.000 2.000000
2011-10-03 03:00:00.000 1.000000
2011-10-03 04:00:00.000 8.000000
2011-10-03 05:00:00.000 5.000000
2011-10-03 06:00:00.000 6.000000

and a mySelectDate = '2011-12-03' (only date)

I have to get the Sum of the Quantity values for each hour of this day (December 3rd).

In this case: 3+1+2+1+8+5+6 = 26

How can I make?


Luigi

Comment: @Ciupaz Could you please write your code in the question so that it is properly formatted? Thanks